# Extracting strings in specified format in python

Tags: python, string

In python Im writing code to extract string from alphanumeric characters. The code should extract only string and print in the following format.

Input should be given in the form of `IND1234AUS1234` (i.e Characters must be separated by few digits)

For the above input python code should extract string `IND` and `AUS` and print as `IND to AUS`

Input must not given in any other formats other than mentioned above and if given in wrong format, code should print invalid input. (example of wrong formats of inputs are 1234INDAUS, IND1234, 123IND123AUS, INDAUS1234)

Below is the code i have tried. It extracts string but I don't know how to seperate and print as `IND to AUS`

My program prints only INDAUS

```
test_string  = input()
only_alpha = ""
for char in test_string:
    if char.isalpha():
      only_alpha += char
print(only_alpha)
```

Please help me with the code. I don't know to write code for validating invalid inputs as i mentioned above.

Comment: You can use `re.findall([A-Z]+,your_string)`

Comment: Is there any constraint on the number of letters and digits ?

Comment: No. There are no constraints on number of letters and digits. Its letters followed by digits and again letters followed by digits.

Comment: Preferably letters of atleast 2 or 3 characters and atleast one digit followed after letters like IND12AUS1234.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You whould use a regex to

1. validate the content `[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]+\d+` : upper with digits twice
2. retrieve the uppercase content at the same time `([A-Z]+)\d+([A-Z]+)\d+` parenthesis to make captuting group anr get content with `.groups()`

```
def extract(value):
    m = re.search(r"([A-Z]+)\d+([A-Z]+)\d+", value)
    if m:
        return " to ".join(m.groups())
    return "Invalid Input"
```

Testing

```
value = "IND1234AUS1234 "
res = extract(value)
print(res)  # IND to AUS

value = "INDAUS1234 "
res = extract(value)  # Invalid Input
print(res)
```

---

A regex that checks the length of each part would be

```
"([A-Z]{2,5})\d{1,5}([A-Z]{2,5})\d{1,5}"
```

Comment: @azro For invalid input just print  Invalid input.

Comment: @AshokKumar Sorry to tell you that but this is very basic code, don't call me genius ;) Also you have to understand it, understand why it return the good string a in case, and why 'invalid' in the other case. Also I've edit to put at the end the regex that check the length of each part

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect way to use regex:

```
def validate(a):
    match = re.match("([A-Z]+)[0-9]+([A-Z]+)[0-9]+", a)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError()
    else:
        return match[1] + " to " + match[2]

>>> validate("IND1234AUS1234")
"IND to AUS"
>>> validate("USD1234EUR1234")
"USD to EUR"
>>> validate("123IND123AUS")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    validate("123IND123AUS")
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 4, in validate
    raise ValueError()
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: <no detail available>
```

Quick explanation: `"([A-Z]+)[0-9]+([A-Z]+)[0-9]+"`

- `([A-Z]+)`: One or more A-Z characters, in parenthesis so we can index them later
- `[0-9]+`: One or more digits

Comment: You should raise `ValueError` instead of `SyntaxError`

Comment: @Ch3steR Now changed